# ctrl key not working, GRUB unresponsive

Tags: grub2, keyboard

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, with a thinkpad 450. While some Ubuntu updates were installing today, my ctrl key got stuck (acted as if it was always pressed down). I restarted the computer and now my left ctrl key is not working at all (it doesn't register in xev). Also, for some reason I cannot navigate GRUB or the BIOS the regular way (the arrow keys do nothing in GRUB, but for some reason the F key selects an entry like ENTER usually would. I managed to enter the BIOS by mashing lots of keys during startup, but it's completely unresponsive and beeps when I press most keys).

Perhaps it's just a hardware failure, but since it happened while installing an update, I wondered whether it might be Ubuntu's fault (and on thinkpads the left ctrl key is special because it can be swapped with the fn key in the BIOS). Any advice?